# How to count the avarage of 3 columns and if the value of each row is greater than certain number then create new column and add defult number

Tags: python

How to count the avarage of 3 columns and if the value of each row is greater than certain number then create new column and add defult number

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 5 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 |
| Cell 7 | Cell 8 | Cell 9 |

if the avarge of each row is less than (0.001) it will create new column and print defult value

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 5 | 1 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 |  |
| Cell 7 | Cell 8 | Cell 9 | 1 |

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 5 | 1 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 |  |
| Cell 7 | Cell 8 | Cell 9 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np    
df['new_column'] = np.where(np.mean(df[['column A',
                              'Columns B','column C']]) <= 0.0001,
                                 default_value,0)
```

Just replace 0 by the value you want if the condition is not satisfied

Answer (score 0):

I find that it works when sperate into two steps

```
default_value = 3
import numpy as np    
df['new_column']= df[['column A', 'Columns B','column C']].mean(axis=1)

df['new_column2'] =  np.where(df['new_column'] <= 0.001, default_value, 0)
```